# How can I get notifications when someone comments on my commit on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, notifications

At the moment I do not get notifications when I someone comments on my commit in GitHub.

Is there any way that I can be notified (web or email) when someone comments on my commit in GitHub?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Couldn’t you have asked this on the products own support page?

Comment: Yes, but I reckoned I would get a quicker response here.

Comment: Sadly too true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are "Watching" the repository, I think you will get notified. Alternatively, you can click the "Subscribe" button on each individual commit like in the bottom left corner of the screenshot below. I am not sure if there is a setting that auto-subscribes to only commits by you, however.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer. I was looking for the answer to this for some time. I really appreciate it!